# ListPlot3D with individual colours for each point that blend

Tags: visualization

If I have a list of points {x,y,z} and for each point an rgb colour, e.g.:
`points={{0,0,0,1,0,0}, {1,0,0,0,1,0}, {1,1,1,0,0,1}}`
how can I plot the surface covering the given points (ListPlot3D) and colour it with blends of the individual colours?

In the above example, I expect a triangle with a red, green and blue corner and in-between blends of the three colours depending on the distance to the corners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option `VertexColors` with `ListPlot3D`:

```
ListPlot3D[points[[All, ;; 3]],  
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 VertexColors -> (RGBColor @@@ points[[All, 4 ;;]])]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
points2 = RandomReal[1, {20, 6}]; 

ListPlot3D[points2[[All, ;; 3]], 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 VertexColors -> (RGBColor @@@ points2[[All, 4 ;;]])]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a starting point, which you can customize to your needs:

```
colourListPlot3D[data_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{pts2d = data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]},
  Graphics3D[
   GraphicsComplex[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]],
    MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[pts2d], 2],
    VertexColors -> data[[All, 4]]
    ],
   opt
   ]
  ]
```

I am assuming an input in the format `data = {{x1, y1, z1, color1}, ...}`.

```
points = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}};

data = {#1, #2, #3, RGBColor[##4]} & @@@ points;

colourListPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation on how this works.